# SwiftUI performance issue showing conditional views in Items in a ForEach loop embedded in aScrollView

Tags: performance, if-statement, foreach, swiftui, scrollview

Working with SwiftUI:

I have a list of views in a ScrollView that I am creating using a ForEach loop. I want to show or hide a number of little flags depending on 4 different Bool properties in the struct I am using as the model for the objects in the list. The problem I'm having is the more If-statements I add, the worse the performance gets. With no If-statements the list loads without a hitch. I'm running into this problem with only 120 items in the list. I would love help figuring out what I'm doing wrong!

Here is an example of the Content View with the ScrollView and loop:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model = Model()


  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true){
      VStack(spacing: 10){
        ForEach(model.list){ item in
          ItemView(item: item)
        }
      }
    }
  }// end body
} // end struct
```

And the Item Views and Struct I'm using as the model.

```
struct ListData: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID()
  var title: String
  var subtitle: String
  var isTrue: Bool
  var isAlsoTrue:Bool
}

struct ItemView: View {
  var item: ListData

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
      Text(item.title)
      HStack{
        if item.isTrue{
          FlagView(text: "True")
        }
        if item.isAlsoTrue{
          FlagView(text: "Also")
        }
        Text(item.subtitle)
        Spacer()
      }
      .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .semibold))
    }
    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold))
  }
}

struct FlagView: View {
  var text: String
  var body: some View {
    Text(text)
      .padding(2)
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2).foregroundColor(.gray))
  }
}
```

The Actual objects have 4 Bool properties I want to use. Is there a better way to hide or show these flags in my list? Any help figuring out what's wrong with the performance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ScrollView does not reuse views and draws/lays out everything at once, just in case. Why don't you use List if you have big dynamic collection?

Comment: At the moment it seems like List doesn't have enough customization, for instance changing the background color, so I'm stuck with scrollview for the moment..

Comment: Even when using a List or the new LazyVGrid (iOS 14), I still have performances issues using a condition on a view. If I remove the condition, the app runs smoothly. Have you found a solution @spenser?

Comment: @alpennec Sadly I had been using the tableview workarounds to style a List view. Now with 14, that has been deprecated, so I'm back to scrollviews with bad performance... no solutions anywhere!

Comment: Could you solve the problem? I'm running in the same problem...

Comment: Would using `.overlay()` help improve the performance? Use conditionals for their opacity property. For example. `.overlay(FlagView(text: "True").opacity(item.isTrue ? 1: 0))`

Answer (score 0):

Coz of you do very big mistake when using `var id = UUID()` in this case any change in this collection will do all the list items render again.
NEVER EVER DO `var id = UUID()` in `Identifiable`, collection is value type any small change - and you get all the items recreated with new `UUID()` SwiftUI sees this new `id` and decides that views should be rendered from scratch!

Second Mistake: viewModel for view should be not used in view as `@ObservableObject var` but should be used as `@StateObject var`, otherwise each time view will be rendered view model will be recreated!